# Replace letters on the whole page, but not within the tags

Tags: php, regex

I've been searching for this for days.. but no result.

I want to replace latin letters with cyrillic ones using php. But I want to exclude some words and letters within the specific tag `<notranslate>`

So if I have:

```
<p><b>Ovo je neki tekst</b> i ovo sigurno <notranslate>nece preci u cirilicu</translate>, hvala !</p>
```

I want it to become:

```
<p><b>Ово је неки текст</b> и ово сигурно <notranslate>nece preci u cirilicu</translate>, хвала !</p>
```

How to do this, using regex ?

Comment: I dont you can do this with a regex. You could use `str_replace` to replace specific characters but that seems like a long road to go down.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your question:

1) how to transliterate latin characters to cyrillic character?

2) how to preserve parts enclosed between "notranslate" tags?

For the first question, I haven't found a way to do it with `iconv`. So, a solution is to use `strtr` with an associative array where latin characters are associated with cyrillic characters. Note that I'm not an expert in cyrillic, so feel free to edit this array to fit your needs.

The second problem is easy to solve using an XPath query to selects only text nodes that haven't the tag "notranslate" as ancestor.

```
$trans = [ 'a'=>'а', 'b'=>'б', 'v'=>'в', 'g'=>'г', 'd'=>'д', 'e'=>'е', 'e'=>'ё', 'zh'=>'ж', 'z'=>'з', 'i'=>'и', 'y'=>'й', 'k'=>'к', 'l'=>'л', 'm'=>'м', 'n'=>'н', 'o'=>'о', 'p'=>'п', 'r'=>'р', 's'=>'с', 't'=>'т', 'u'=>'у', 'f'=>'ф', 'h'=>'х', 'ts'=>'ц', 'ch'=>'ч', 'sh'=>'ш', 'sht'=>'щ', 'i'=>'ъ', 'y'=>'ы', 'y'=>'ь', 'e'=>'э', 'yu'=>'ю', 'ya'=>'я', 'A'=>'А', 'B'=>'Б', 'V'=>'В', 'G'=>'Г', 'D'=>'Д', 'E'=>'Е', 'E'=>'Ё', 'Zh'=>'Ж', 'Z'=>'З', 'I'=>'И', 'Y'=>'Й', 'K'=>'К', 'L'=>'Л', 'M'=>'М', 'N'=>'Н', 'O'=>'О', 'P'=>'П', 'R'=>'Р', 'S'=>'С', 'T'=>'Т', 'U'=>'У', 'F'=>'Ф', 'H'=>'Х', 'Ts'=>'Ц', 'Ch'=>'Ч', 'Sh'=>'Ш', 'Sht'=>'Щ', 'I'=>'Ъ', 'Y'=>'Ы', 'Y'=>'Ь', 'E'=>'Э', 'Yu'=>'Ю', 'Ya'=>'Я' ];

$html = '<p><b>Ovo je neki tekst</b> i ovo sigurno <notranslate>nece <p>preci</p> u cirilicu</notranslate>, hvala !</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $html . '</div>');

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xp->query('//text()[not(ancestor::notranslate)]');

foreach ($textNodes as $textNode) {
   $textNode->nodeValue = strtr($textNode->nodeValue, $trans);
}

$result ='';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveXML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```